# Difference between "indefinite" and "indecisive"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *indefinite* and *indecisive*, and when do you use each one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Indefinite**

1-vague,  not clearly defined

> ... so indefinite that it is confusing.

2-no fixed end

> ... voted to begin an indefinite strike

**Indecisive**

1-having difficulty with  "decisions" or "choices"

> a weak and indecisive leader

2-inconclusive

> The outcome of the battle was indecisive.

Answer (score 2):

You should use *indefinite* in a situation which is difficult to define: there are various many possible explanations and it's difficult to say which of them is true. For example:

> I went through the numbers over and over again and the results were indefinite. I don't think we can get a clear, definite answer on this.

On the other hand, you should use *indecisive* when there are only a few options being compared and chosen from, like:

> The two runners entered the finish line both at once. The referees had a hard time with the indecisive results.